# Is $\sum i^{1/i}$ bounded?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, radicals

I'm trying to find the limit 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i^{1/i}}n\,.
$$ 
I was going to say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n=0$ and $\sum i^{1/i}$ is bounded but I can't prove it.

Comment: $\sum i^{1/i}$ isn't bounded, since the terms converge to $1$. However, $i^{1/i}<2$, so your sum is less than $\sum_{i=1}^n 2/n = 2$

Answer (score 5):

You should use the following fact:

*If $a_n\to a$, then $\,\,\dfrac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n}\to a,\,\,\,$ as well.*

This is a consequence of [Cesàro-Stolz Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

In our case
$$
a_n=n^{1/n}\to 1,
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{1^{1/1}+2^{1/2}+\cdots+n^{1/n}}{n}\to 1.
$$

Comment: This fact is the theorem of somebody, isn't it?

Comment: It's Cesàro summation.

Answer (score 2):

First,

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}k^{1/k}=\exp\left(\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\log k}k\right)=\exp0=1$$

Thus, there exists some $k_0$ such that $k> k_0$ implies $k^{1/k}\geq 1/2$. Let $$A=\sum_{k=1}^{k_0}k^{1/k}-\frac{k_0}2$$

Then, for $n> k_0$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^{1/k}=\sum_{k=1}^{k_0} k^{1/k}+\sum_{k=k_0+1}^n k^{1/k}\geq A+\frac n2$$

So you can't prove that $\sum k^{1/k}$ is bounded. Simply because it is false.

Sorry for the change of notation (your $i$ is my $k$) but I only use $i$ for $\sqrt{-1}$.